# How to make a function that inserts a node into the front of this queue?

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

This is code is from geeksforgeeks, and I'm trying to use it for a round robin scheduler. Normally, the function enQueue() adds the node to the back of the queue, and since I didn't write this, I'm unsure of how to modify the push() function to insert to the back. My only attempt kept resulting in a segfault.

```
/* Program to implement a queue using one user defined stack  
and one Function Call Stack */
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

/* structure of a stack node */
struct sNode { 
    int data; 
    struct sNode* next; 
}; 

/* structure of queue having two stacks */
struct queue { 
    struct sNode* stack1; 
}; 

/* Function to push an item to stack*/
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data); 

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref); 

/* Function to enqueue an item to queue */
void enQueue(struct queue* q, int x) 
{ 
    push(&q->stack1, x); 
} 

/* Function to deQueue an item from queue */
int deQueue(struct queue* q) 
{ 
    int x, res; 

    /* If both stacks are empty then error */
    if (q->stack1 == NULL) { 
        printf("Q is empty"); 
        getchar(); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else if (q->stack1->next == NULL) { 
        return pop(&q->stack1); 
    } 
    else { 
        /* pop an item from the stack1 */
        x = pop(&q->stack1); 

        /* store the last deQueued item */
        res = deQueue(q); 

        /* push everything back to stack1 */
        push(&q->stack1, x); 
        return res; 
    } 
} 

/* Function to push an item to stack*/
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    /* allocate node */
    struct sNode* new_node = (struct sNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct sNode)); 

    if (new_node == NULL) { 
        printf("Stack overflow \n"); 
        getchar(); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    /* put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data; 

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*top_ref); 

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*top_ref) = new_node; 
} 

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref) 
{ 
    int res; 
    struct sNode* top; 

    /*If stack is empty then error */
    if (*top_ref == NULL) { 
        printf("Stack underflow \n"); 
        getchar(); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else { 
        top = *top_ref; 
        res = top->data; 
        *top_ref = top->next; 
        free(top); 
        return res; 
    } 
} 

/* Driver function to test above functions */
int main() 
{ 
    /* Create a queue with items 1 2 3*/
    struct queue* q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue)); 
    q->stack1 = NULL; 

    enQueue(q, 1); 
    enQueue(q, 2); 
    enQueue(q, 3); 

    /* Dequeue items */
    printf("%d ", deQueue(q)); 
    printf("%d ", deQueue(q)); 
    printf("%d ", deQueue(q)); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `enqueue` and `push` functions both? Are you trying to construct a double-ended queue?

Comment: Ok, I've seen the code at [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-using-stacks/). That one implements a queue using two stacks. But (apparently) you're trying to modify your stack-based approach... into a real queue. Is that the case? Then I don't see the point in rewriting push/pop. You should just get rid of all that.